# What is this invasive plant with with small purplish flowers that have lids?

Tags: identification, weeds

What is this plant/weed with with unusual purplish flowers and new growth leaves? Flowers have "lids".

Its habit is similar to white clover's fill-the-space habit, and it took over significant parts of my yard. I am going to remove it (if I can), but I am courious what is it. Bees love flowers though.

It is mid-March, zone 8a.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so those "lids" are for spreading pollen on the backs of bees?

Comment: It is, as already said, Lamium purpureum - it's native to Europe and Asia.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamium_purpureum. There is a wide range of other Lamium varieties you can buy with variously coloured leaves - L. purpureum is the 'wildflower' or 'weed' version

Comment: https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/cgi/img_query?query_src=photos_index&where-taxon=Lamium+purpureum. This link to a photo gallery is from wikipedia page that @bamboo posted. Photos really match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ben wrote, it is *Lamium purpureum*. It is also the typus (the official representative) of Lamium (genus), and of the large family of Lamiaceae (family, previously also know as Labiatae).

Later you will probably seen his brower *Lamium maculatum*, which has larger flowers and with some more distance between flowers.

Most of Lamiaceae have such typical flower, usually with a label, 4 anthers (often 2 long and two short). Typical is also the square stem and perfume to odor.

Basilicum, rosemary, thyme, lavender, etc are gardening plant of such family.

The white flowers in the same photos are *Stellaria media*, you have *Taraxacum*, I think *Arabis turita* (or something similar), I think also a *Vicia* and a *Trifolium*. You have a lot of diversity on weeds ;-)

Comment: You said I need a diverse garden to attract birds, so I keep diverse weeds. ;) Thanks a lot for additional info!

Comment: @VividD: yeah. BTW the Stellaria media in some languages is named "herb of birds". In winter birds (and chicken) like it,

Answer (score 5):

Looks like *Lamium purpureum*, variously known as Red Henbit, Red Deadnettle & Purple Deadnettle. A herbaceous annual native to Europe and parts of Asia; introduced in the U.S. where it evidently has invasive tendencies.

https://gobotany.newenglandwild.org/species/lamium/purpureum/

https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=LAPU2#